# PS1 variable inheritance between scripts and programs using bash in AIX

Tags: bash, aix, prompt

How can I ensure that PS1 variable in AIX bash is inherited between cross calling of scripts and programs ?

Suppose a program gives to the user a shell instance such as the `shell` command of `vi`. This can be used in two ways, in one of them it's launched by a script (see the 2nd case below):

1. `ksh prompt` -> `program` -> "user asks for shell" -> `ksh`
2. script -> `program` -> "user asks for shell" -> `ksh`

That works well with ksh. But when the bash is used **(in AIX)**, we noticed in the 2nd case that the PS1 variable isn't inherited, so it has the default value.

You can test it just using vi, create a script, like: `runvi.sh`:

```
# blablabla
# vi $1
```

When we run the script and ask vi for the shell, the prompt is: `sh-4.3$`

Of course, when you run vi directly, and it asks for the shell, the prompt is your previously defined PS1.

The unique difference between the test above and the real program is that in the program the bash shows the PS1 with the value `bash-4.3$`, so the issue with PS1 inheritance seems the same. This C program can shows it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
main() { system("$SHELL"); }
```

**BASH VERSION:**

```
bash-4.3$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (powerpc-ibm-aix5.1.0.0)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

**AIX VERSION**

The same behavior between AIX 5.3 until 7.

**OBS:** In Ubuntu this doesn't happen.

Comment: You'll probably want `system("$SHELL -li")` to have it source your login config files. Many programs hardcode `/bin/sh` as a "system shell": in that case, you have no control.

Comment: It sounds like you have a ~/.bashrc or similar that is resetting PS1.

Comment: /etc/environment perhaps? Odd place for it, but it's unique to AIX.

Comment: No @JeffSchaller. I tried a lot of things exploring .bashrc and ensured that they are the same as in Ubuntu. I also left just /etc/profile and removed all .bash* and .pro*. The same issue, but just in AIX

Comment: @JeffSchaller, /etc/environment didn't produce effects (I didn't remove /etc/profile)

Comment: @glennjackman: "-il" flag worked, but it's a bash argument which fails with ksh. I'm thinking to check $SHELL content and if it ends with "bash" switch the flow to run "$SHELL -il", otherwise, just "$SHELL". Anyone has suggestions ?

Comment: @glennjackman: Sorry, wrong diagnostic. The flag "-il" didn't work well, because "-l" runs .bash_profile which runs undesired code which should run only one time, at login only. And now trying only "-i" this doesn't work in AIX.

Comment: Solutions didn't worked until now. What about to set PS1 at bash parameters ? How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An workaround:

```
// C code snippet
#define CMDPATTERN_PS1_PRESET "export PS1='%s';$SHELL"
#define CMDPATTERN_PS1_NOSET "$SHELL"

char* cmdpattern = (userPS1!=NULL && *userPS1 != NULL) ?CMDPATTERN_PS1_PRESET :CMDPATTERN_PS1_NOSET;
sprintf(shellcmd, cmdpattern, userPS1);
system(shellcmd);
```

So, if the user wants a custom PS1, in case it isn't inherited, it should be previsouly configured in the software. And can keep working in all shells and OSes.